# VML lineDrawn variable

Tags: java, svg, ms-office, docx4j, vml

Hi guys do you know what the **lineDrawn** variable means? sometimes it is present in vml formula elements. I tried searching for documentation for this but have not found one so far.

Here is the sample shape from MS Word document that I a lineDrawn value.

```
<w:pict>
                       <v:shapetype stroked="f" filled="f" o:spt="75.0" o:preferrelative="t" path="m@4@5l@4@11@9@11@9@5xe" coordsize="21600,21600" id="_x0000_t75">
                                <v:stroke joinstyle="miter"/>
                                <v:formulas>
                                    <v:f eqn="if lineDrawn pixelLineWidth 0"/>
                                    <v:f eqn="sum @0 1 0"/>
                                    <v:f eqn="sum 0 0 @1"/>
                                    <v:f eqn="prod @2 1 2"/>
                                    <v:f eqn="prod @3 21600 pixelWidth"/>
                                    <v:f eqn="prod @3 21600 pixelHeight"/>
                                    <v:f eqn="sum @0 0 1"/>
                                    <v:f eqn="prod @6 1 2"/>
                                    <v:f eqn="prod @7 21600 pixelWidth"/>
                                    <v:f eqn="sum @8 21600 0"/>
                                    <v:f eqn="prod @7 21600 pixelHeight"/>
                                    <v:f eqn="sum @10 21600 0"/>
                                </v:formulas>
                                <v:path gradientshapeok="t" o:connecttype="rect" o:extrusionok="f"/>
                                <o:lock aspectratio="t" v:ext="edit"/>
                            </v:shapetype>
                            <v:shape type="#_x0000_t75" style="position:absolute;left:0;text-align:left;margin-left:20pt;margin-top:9pt;width:151.5pt;height:108pt;z-index:251657216" id="_x0000_s1026">
                                <v:imagedata o:title="" r:id="rId13"/>
                            </v:shape>
                            <o:OLEObject Type="Embed" ProgID="Visio.Drawing.11" ShapeID="_x0000_s1026" DrawAspect="Content" ObjectID="_1466267083" r:id="rId14"/>
                        </w:pict>
```

Ref: http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-VML#_Toc416858392

Comment: Good question; I suggest you ask at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/home?forum=worddev

Comment: or possibly http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=os_binaryfile

Comment: Thank you JasonPlutext,I will be doing that.